# Loading huge list of files in angular.js app for development env

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

In our Angular.js app we're having individual files for every controller, directive, service etc. So there are hundreds of js files to include.

We're using `Grunt` to concat and uglify javascript for production, but I want to load files individually for development environment.

The problem is, in `Gruntfile` you can specify list of files using wildcards, i.e. `/js/**/*.js` to include all the modules of the app.

In development I was thinking about loading files asynchronously like `angular-seed` does, but the `$script` loader doesn't alow wildcards in the path, so I need to specify every single file by hand, which seems... not optimal.

Is there a common practice for this?

Answer (score 2):

Check out Usemin (https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin). It let's you use unconcatenated and unuglfied files in development, and will automatically replace those includes with the concatenated and uglified files on build/deployment. That way you can keep regular includes in your files without having to load them by hand.